# How to specify remote header files and libraries during remote development of C/C++ in Netbeans?

Tags: c++, netbeans, remote-debugging

I am developing a C++ application using Netbeans remote development platform. I don't know how to specify the libraries that are on the remote server, in my local Netbeans IDE. If I go through the normal procedure of specifying them in the project properties, I am getting only the local files and not remote files. please help.

Answer (score -1):

It's the first time that I heard such a "requirement". Why should you want to access files over the internet during development? Why don't you install the needed libraries on your local machine, develop your software and then build a proper installer with all the needed files?

Comment: The libraries are not standard libraries. They part of a big project which is deployed in the server for which I am adding additional functionalities. It will be a pain to set up all the libraries on the local host.Also, I have only read permissions for few libraries on the server so I cannot copy them here.

Comment: That still has a taste of wrongness. For that you should have a revsion control system, you check out the files you need and work with them, and you checkin your sources for the others. It will be a pain by all means to not work locally on your project... AFAIKT

Comment: If I check out the files and checkin I will not get code assistance from netbeans for the dependent libraries right? Also I will not be able to use the debug tools that net beans provide which is the main reason I am trying to do this. If netbeans can reference gcc,g++ remotely, why cant it reference the libraries in the same way? (PS- Am I making no sense??)

Comment: Well netbeans offers intergration for diverse RC systems, and you get whatever support you can get from it. You checkout the proper files, setup your development environment and from there on netbeans works as usual. But maybe I got you wrong and you want to do something different? Have you visited the netbeans homepage and check what they so suggest?

Comment: basically what I want is to use the IDE capabilities for faster coding and debugging. So, I need the entire project to be "recognized" by netbeans. I cant install netbeans on the remote server and take xwindow out because the connection is not that great. So, I want netbeans to be installed in the local system but all the files that it uses(compiler, linker and libraries) must be from the remote host

Comment: pardon, but if you need an executable from a remote server, why don't you use symlinks? Can you `ssh` to there or `nfs`? Sorry, I am thinking it would be only usefull if you are under any Linux OS.

Comment: @RuslanGerasimov yeah both my localhost and remote host are linux. I cant understand how do you create symlink to a directory/file in another computer. can you please elaborate?

Comment: and yeah I can ssh there but not nfs

Comment: As you can `ssh` there you can mount your target folder to your local file system through `sshfs`. Then you just create an ordinary `symlink`. It will operate with remote destination via `sshfs` mounted locally.